# Web Audio API not playing sound

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, web-audio-api

So I have a piano website where you can draw in notes on a screen and press a button to start a playhead, and as the playhead moves along the screen, the notes under it get played. I'm using the Create React app and using `npm start` to launch the app on Chrome

This is the button onClick method:

```
 const onClick = async () => {
    setPlay((prev) => prev ? "" : "play");
    if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
        await audioContext.resume();
        console.log("resumed");
        console.log(audioContext.state);
    }
  };
```

As the playhead progress, I have a prop called `progress` that stores that value and updates every frame (so 30fps)

This is the code for a note that the user draws in.

```
export function Note(props) {

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

let note;
// fetching the audio from file in the public folder

    fetch(props.filePath)
        .then(data => data.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
        .then(decodedAudio => {
            note = decodedAudio;
        });

    const isPlayed = (offset) => {
        // returns boolean if note is being played or note
    };

// stores current progress

    useEffect(() => {
        setPlayed(isPlayed(props.progress));
    }, [props.progress]);

// plays note if played value changes

    useEffect(() => {
        if (played) {
            playNote();
        } else {
            audioContext.suspend();
        }
    }, [played]);

// plays note

    const playNote = () => {
        const play = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        play.buffer = note;
        play.connect(audioContext.destination);
        play.start();

    };

return (
    // displays the note on screen

    <div><div>
);

}
```

I made sure to resume the Audio Context upon button click. But for some reason, the sound just isn't playing. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: the file Path seems to be correct because I can see the file being loaded in the network

Comment: Did you check that the path to the sound (props.filePath) is right?

Comment: @ManuelMB I'm using the public folder, and I have a folder called notes in there. So its "/notes/filename.wav". I saw somewhere that react finds the file automatically if its in the public folder. And i checked the network and the file is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

This code works ok:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <script src="playNote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="playButton">Play Sound</button>
</body>
</html>
```

- playNote.js

  ```
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();

    let note;

    // fetching the audio from file in the the same folder that this file

    fetch('beach.mp3')
    .then(data => data.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => 
          audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
    .then(decodedAudio => {
         note = decodedAudio;
     })

    const playNote = () => {
        const play = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        play.buffer = note;
        play.connect(audioContext.destination);
        play.start();
    };

    function handleClick() {
       playNote() 
     }

   window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
       const playButton = document.getElementById('playButton')
       playButton.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    });
  ```

Take a look to:

[chrome://settings/content?search=sound](https://chrome://settings/content?search=sound)

[image: Sound Chrome settings]

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing this, but for some reason, it doesn't work on Chrome. I tried on Microsoft Edge and it works perfectly there. Am I missing something in how Web Audio works in Chrome?

Comment: It works on Chrome for me. Take a look of how are you calling the function playNote() (If you call it without user interaction Chrome shows the following Error:

The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.